# How to add custom field to invoice in NetSuite

Tags: netsuite

I just tried to add field into invoice.

I created fields in Transaction Body Fields(Customization/Lists,Records & Fields/Transaction Body Fields) and make Access to Full Access and display to main 
but I couldn't find it in Invoice record.

Where could I find this?

Comment: Did you selected the appropriate record types from the Applies to tab ?

Comment: Sorry but I checked appropriate record types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your custom field definition, you also need to click "Apply to Forms" and make sure your new field is enabled on all applicable forms. Then, clear your browser cache before viewing an Invoice record.

Comment: Thanks. but let me ask one more. I want to put my field to Sales Information section. Though I changed it into Main, insert before position I want, but it is not working properly.  What can I do?

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of the form showing the current location of the field and the desired location?

Comment: Could you tell me how to add custom transaction column pls